# How can I connect a custom user info web part to an image web part?

Tags: web-part, connected-web-parts

I have 2 web parts:

1. SP2010 default image slideshow
2. Custom userinfo from profile db

I have user name (domain\username) in webpart 1 which I want to pass to webpart 2 to get user info at the same time as when the image gets refreshed.

Any way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunatley the Slideshow Web Part does not have any consumer connections. You need to build a custom slideshow Web Part to be able to connect it to another WP.